# avrdude programmer is not responding when uploading a .hex file

Tags: eclipse, arduino-uno, atmega, avr-gcc, avrdude

I'm trying to upload a hex file to atmega328 on my arduino UNO board that I builded with eclipse's AVR plugin but when I run `avrdude -pm328p -carduino -P/dev/ttyACM0 -b9600 -Uflash:w:/home/bruno/workspace/testAVR/Release/testAVR.hex:a` I get `avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding`

I tried to upload a blink led code using arduino IDE and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly general error that can be caused by any number of things. Try adding a `-vvv` flag (or maybe `-vvvv`) which will give you more verbose output when programming.

One thing to try is hitting the reset button on the Arduino immediately after avrdude writes the first few bytes.

Ensure that there is nothing shorted, and that the Uno has a stable power source. Also, if there is anything connected to the RX/TX pins, that can cause a programming issue.

Make sure you are using the correct programmer, if your Arduino is a clone, you might need `-c arduino-ft232r`.